# How to pass bytes32 to Web3.methods.function.call

Tags: solidity, ecrecover, ecdsa

I have a contract that is doing an ecrecover:

```
function recover(bytes32 h, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) public returns (address) {                
      return ecrecover(h, v, r, s);
}
```

It works fine in my truffle unit tests

```
console.log(await ecdsa.recover.call('0xbec921276c8067fe0c82def3e5ecfd8447f1961bc85768c2a56e6bd26d3c0c53', '0x1b', '0x6c5b9b4deb51a4733784657abac3e1dcef04086979a500397456b948981ccbc1', '0x2944200fb10074295baa04db6c048dc120ee9f3b48a42cbe4223242f07cc8e85'));
```

But when I use web3@1.0.0 and the contract ABI in NodeJs I receive an error:

```
const contract = new this.web3.eth.Contract(this.abi.abi, this.abi.networks['5777'].address);    
await contract.methods.recover.call('0xbec921276c8067fe0c82def3e5ecfd8447f1961bc85768c2a56e6bd26d3c0c53', '0x1b', '0x6c5b9b4deb51a4733784657abac3e1dcef04086979a500397456b948981ccbc1', '0x2944200fb10074295baa04db6c048dc120ee9f3b48a42cbe4223242f07cc8e85', (err, result) => { console.log(err); console.log(result);});


{ Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":4,"values":0}, value={"types":[{"name":"h","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"v","type":"uint8"},{"name":"r","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"s","type":"bytes32"}],"values":[]}, version=4.0.27)
```

Answer (score 0):

With web3 v1 you  should pass the parameters with the method and not call (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call).

Something like this should work

```
await contract.methods.recover(
    '0xbec921276c8067fe0c82def3e5ecfd8447f1961bc85768c2a56e6bd26d3c0c53', 
    '0x1b', 
    '0x6c5b9b4deb51a4733784657abac3e1dcef04086979a500397456b948981ccbc1', 
    '0x2944200fb10074295baa04db6c048dc120ee9f3b48a42cbe4223242f07cc8e85'
).call((err, result) => { 
    console.log(err); 
    console.log(result);
});
```